# Eliminar valor repetido en chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

Estoy realizando un grafico de líneas con chartjs, pero el problema que tengo que el eje Y está repitiendo valores, desearía que esto no ocurriera y el dato solo se mostrara una vez, así es como se muestra:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es mi código:

```
const dataSet = {
        labels: this.labelsCharLine,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Setpoint',
            data: dataTeorico,
            borderColor: '#FD1F9B',
            borderWidth: 2,
            backgroundColor: '#FD1F9B',
            pointBackgroundColor: '#FD1F9B', // Color del relleno del punto
            pointBorderColor: '#FD1F9B', // Color del borde del punto
            pointRadius: 4,
            fill: false,
          },
          {
            label: 'Real',
            data: dataReal,
            borderColor: '#017EFA',
            borderWidth: 2,
            backgroundColor: this.transparentize('#254BD1', 0.8),
            pointBackgroundColor: '#017EFA', // Color del relleno del punto
            pointBorderColor: '#017EFA', // Color del borde del punto
            pointRadius: 4, // Tamaño de los puntos
            fill: true,
          },
        ],
      };

      const numTeorico = this.obtenerNumeroMayor(dataTeorico);
      const numTReal = this.obtenerNumeroMayor(dataReal);

      const max = numTeorico > numTReal ? numTeorico : numTReal;

      const lineOptions = computed<ChartOptions<'line'>>(() => ({
        scales: {
          x: {
            title: {
              font: {
                family: 'Montserrat-SemiBold',
                size: 10,
                weight: 'bold',
              },
              padding: { top: 15, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 11 },
              gridLines: { color: '#ffffff' },
            },
          },
          y: {
            stacked: false
          },

          scales: {
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left',
            min: 0,
            max: Number(max + max * 0.3),
            ticks: {
              callback: (value) => {
                return this.transformarNumeroAbreviado(Number(value));
              },
              // stepSize: 50000,
            },
            grid: {
              display: false,
              drawBorder: false,
            },
          },
        },

        plugins: {
          datalabels: {
            display: false,
          },
          legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom',
            labels: {
              color: 'black',
              usePointStyle: true,
              pointStyle: 'circle',
              padding: 20,
              boxWidth: 7,
              boxHeight: 7,
            },
          },
          filler: {
            propagate: true,
          },
        },
      }));

      this.chartLineConsumoAcumulado = useLineChart({
        chartData: computed<ChartData<'line'>>(() => ({
          labels: dataSet.labels,
          datasets: dataSet.datasets,
        })),
        options: lineOptions,
      }).lineChartProps;
    },
```